# Class member qualified name lookup

Tags: c++, class, language-lawyer

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
    int b[A::a]; //1, error
    void foo(){ int b = A::a; } //2, ok
    static const int a = 5;
}
```

Clause 3.4.3.1/1 (Qualified name lookup, class members) said:

> If the nested-name-specifier of a qualified-id nominates a class, the
>   name specified after the nested-name-specifier is looked up in the
>   scope of the class **(10.2)**

This implies that the name `a` after the nested-name-specifier both in `//1` and in `//2` will be looked up in the class scope.

Clause 10.2 (Member name lookup) said:

*10.2/2*

> The following steps define the result of name lookup for a member name
>   f in a class scope C.

*10.2/3*

> The lookup set for f in C, called S(f, C)...
>
> S(f, C) is calculated as follows:

*10.2/4*

> If C contains a declaration of the name f, the declaration set
>   contains every declaration of f declared in C that satisfies the
>   requirements of the language construct in which the lookup occurs.

**The following is unclear for me:**

From the quotes I cited implies that for both `//1` and `//2` the same member lookup rules shall be applied. **But actually its a different.** Why is my reasoning wrong?

***Note***: I know about unqualified name lookup rules into the class scope. And I understood that  behavior in the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
    int b[a]; //error
    void foo(){ int b = a; } //ok
    static const int a = 5;
}
```

It is because that behavior described in the sections 3.4.1/7 and 3.4.1/8 (Unqualified name lookup).

Comment: This title is merely the name of a language feature. Good titles describe the question posed, instead of simply naming language features. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253766/46642

Answer (score 4):

The error is because when `int b[A::a];` is being processed, `A` does not yet have a symbol `a`. At that point of compilation, `A` is still incomplete because we have not reached the closing `}` of the class definition yet. The compiler doesn't "look ahead" to see if future lines of source code contain a definition of `a`.

You can see this by reversing the order of the lines:

```
class A
{
    static const int a = 5;
    int b[A::a]; // OK
};
```

The function definition does not have the same problem because inline function bodies are not compiled until after compilation of the class definition. (Sorry, I don't have standard references handy for this)

Comment: Does a suitable standard reference exist at all?

Answer (score 3):

The member declaration `int b[A::a];` is not in the *potential scope* of `A::a` (3.3.7p1), while the body of `void A::foo()` is in the potential scope (3.3.7p1b1):

> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the name's point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, *brace-or-equal-initializers* of non-static data members, and default arguments in that class (including such things in nested classes).

3.4.3.1p1 references the potential scope rule in a note:

> [...] [ *Note:* A class member can be referred to using a qualified-id at any point in its potential scope (3.3.7). *— end note* ] [...]

Of course, notes are non-normative, so the conclusion must be that the potential scope rule is implied by other material in the standard.  I believe this other material is specifically 3.3.2p5:

> After the point of declaration of a class member, the member name can be looked up in the scope of its class. [...]

By implication, prior to the point of declaration of that class member, that member name *cannot* be looked up in the scope of that class.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. But can you clarify the following: from the fact that class member can be referred to using a qualified-id at any point in its potential scope does not implies that **that class member cannot be referred outside of it potential scope**. Moreover it is not true. Actually, using qualified-id we can use a class member outside of it scope. Applying that I assume that scope reasoning is not correct in my case. Maybe I did not understand you?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv using a qualified-id, you can access a class member outside its scope, but you cannot access that class member outside its *potential* scope. Note that in addition to function bodies within the class etc., the potential scope includes the entire remainder of the translation unit after the point of declaration.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv again, note the example in the note to 3.3.2p5; this illustrates that in the absence of that paragraph the member could not be looked up in the scope of its class at all.